# Selendroid error while setup in windows get error in cmd

Tags: eclipse, selendroid

I have setup eclipse, sdk, path, configuration selendroid -standaloe-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar file and selenium server.jar file but with command prompt want to run server with this command `java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar -aut testapp.apk` but in command prompt it displayed error like `unable to access`[image] jar file.."

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to folder permission issues or jar file getting corrupt. Could you please move the jar file to a different folder and try running again or download the jar again.

Also, you may refer the following post for more troubleshooting options:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- right click on "selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar" file in Windows Explorer, then open "Properties" and click on "Unblock" button in the bottom, then try again;
- or if it will not help, try to execute `java -jar "./selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar" -aut testapp.apk`

Answer (score 0):

1. double click on the "selenium*.jar" and Java jar file.
2. Go to the command prompt and write the full path of your
   directory where the above jar file exist.
   for example, C:>CD enter
3. write below command and then press enter key. your selenim server
   will be automatically started.
   java -jar selenium*.jar

Good Luck